# How to bind a List (one or more times)?

Tags: java, swing, data-binding

I follow the Presentation Model pattern for coding some screens.

- I store some Beans in an `ArrayList`
- I will display the content of this List in a `JTable`, thanks to an `AbstractTableModel`
- I also want to display **some** records from this list in a Combo Box (in a form) **and some others** in a JList, **at the same time**
- **These three screens (and their model) are independent from each other**

How to manage add {one or more}/remove {one or more} on my List and view changes in "real-time" everywhere?

I'm about to write my own ObservableList or implement that around an EventDispatcher... What do you think?

---

PS:

- I know that in C# the `BindingList` helps for that purpose, what about Java?
- I'm already able to display updates of each bean, thanks to `PropertyChangeSupport`.

Comment: You should take a look JGoodies binding, it's based on PresentationModel pattern and should fit your problem..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let your `AbstractTableModel` implement [`ListModel`](http://cs.adelaide.edu.au/docs/java/javax/swing/ListModel.html), which is usable with both `JComboBox and`JList. You can forward methods to the default model implementations as required.

Addendum: [`SharedModelDemo`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SharedModelDemoProject/src/components/SharedModelDemo.java), mentioned in [*How to Use Tables*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), is an example that may get you started. It `extends DefaultListModel implements TableModel`, while you should do `extends AbstractTableModel implements ListModel`

Addendum: For reference, here's an outline of the minimal implementation and three test instantiations. I've used the default combo and list implementations, but you can use the corresponding abstract implementations if necessary.

```
public class SharedModel extends AbstractTableModel
        implements ComboBoxModel, ListModel {
    private ComboBoxModel comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    private ListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();

    //ComboBoxModel
    @Override
    public void setSelectedItem(Object anItem) {
        comboModel.setSelectedItem(anItem);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSelectedItem() {
        return comboModel.getSelectedItem();
    }

    // ListModel
    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return listModel.getSize();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getElementAt(int index) {
        return listModel.getElementAt(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void addListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {
        listModel.addListDataListener(l);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {
        listModel.removeListDataListener(l);
    }

    // TableModel
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                SharedModel sm = new SharedModel();
                JTable table = new JTable(sm);
                JList list = new JList(sm);
                JComboBox check = new JComboBox(sm);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your answer! Your advice is to implement a kind of "swiss knife" model, that's it? But, will I have to inject this shared model to each sub model who represents each screen? If yes, I have to find another solution, because each screen is developed in a separate module.
What do you think if I implement the "ListModel like" (`ObservableList`) at lower level (in a separate module, without any dependency to javax.swing) and share it with all screens? Like this, every sub-model will be able to receive add/remove/update notifications?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. A shared model can have an arbitrary number of listening views. `AbstractListModel` can provide event handling for either `JList` or `JComboBox`, much as `AbstractTableModel` does for `JTable`. Your data model is hierarchical?

Comment: I apologies if I'm not clear enough. So, my concern is to keep separated each screen and their own model(s). In my mind, if I have a screen with a `JTable` I have to extend an `AbstractTableModel` to "feed" the JTable. If I have another screen with a JList (showing the same data) I would extend a dedicated `AbstractListModel`.
At a lower level, both `AbstractTableModel` and `AbstractListModel` will listen events on the same "Observable List" (totally uncoupled from swing) .... Maybe I'm wrong, let me know, please. - No, my data model is not hierarchical.

Comment: Right, the model remains separate. I've outlined such a `SharedModel` above. A single instance of it can be passed to the constructor of all three views: table, combo and list. You'll have to "fill in" the data, of course.

Comment: @Destroyica "So, my concern is to keep separated each screen and their own model(s)" Either they show the same data (and allow "real time" changes) or not :-) It's okay to share the _model_, in fact that's the whole point of the pattern

Comment: Thank you guys, long life to SO!

Answer (score 2):

For the JComboBox and the JList you could simply reference sections of the ArrayList using the subList() method. This will work if you can easily identify the starting and ending locations within the ArrayList and the elements you need are sequential.

If the situation is more dynamic than that you could implement custom List classes that took the ArrayList in the constructor and then apply whatever logic you need to return the appropriate records.

Comment: Effectively, the situation is more dynamic: I want to see the content of my JList and of my Combo Box change in "real time", even more than that: the content of each entry must be updated dynamically.

The subList() is a good idea, but what happens if I remove an entry? My original List will be altered but the JTable won't be notified and won't raise `fireTableRowsDeleted`.