# How to implement multi inheritance in java with interfaces?

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance

I need to mimic multi inheritance in Java. It might be wrong design but, since my problem is not with (parent) class functionality, I have not been able to mimic the feature with interfaces. 
Here is more description on the problem.
I have a class called `AbstractModel.java` with number of methods. On the other hand, there is another class  `AbstractTableModel.java`. Now assume that there is a class called table controller.java that deals with `AbstractModel.java` and on the other hand there is class called `Tableview`.java that deals with `AbstractTableModel.java`. I need have to some way to define : public class A extends `AbstractModel`, `AbstracTableModel` so that both view and controller can use the same class with extension. Please note that the solution `AbstractTableModel.java` extends `AbstractModel` is not a solution since it is a built-in java class.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you make AbstractModel and AstractTableModel interfaces, and then make class A implement those interfaces?

Comment: See also this example of a [`SharedModel`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7572903/230513).

Comment: You can convert 1 class: AbstractModel class or AstractTableModel class into interface, then class A extends 1 class and implements remaining interface.

Comment: since there are many other classes extending the AbstractModel. By making that an interface I have just got very much redundancy by copying the same code in all the children. Abstract table model is java built-in class under javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

Comment: In other words if Class A implements (AbstractModel/AbstractTableModel) as an interface it can not be passed to controller or view accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by "redundancy be copying the same code in all the children"? If you make an Interface for AbstractModel (which is a matter of less than a minute in Eclipse), there is no need to change any of the children, and all methods anywhere else (in the workspace) that before used an `AbstractModel` can in the same step automatically be changed to accept the interface instead.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it directly in Java but you can use [delegation design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern). Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038314/alternative-of-multiple-inheritance-in-java). It is a very similar question on SO.

Comment: hanks @gigadot I think I was not clear enough on my question. As I mentioned before my problem is not functionality. to Summarize: There is a method in view that take AbstracttableModel. i.e. display(AbstractTableModel model) and there is a method in controller that accepts Abstract model i.e. addModel(AbstractModel model). Now how I can add the same model to the controller and display on the view without multiple inheritance? One way that came to my mind was to create a second class that has two members: AbstractModel AM, AbstracTableModel ATM and Pass AM to the controller and ATM to the view

Comment: it is not possible to create a new class that subclass both AbstractModel and AbstracTableModel. If you want to change your controller and view methods' signature just as you described to accept this new class, you are better redesign your model representations.

Comment: Do you know of any particular design pattern that deals with this issue at all other than delegation design pattern for functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code that expects an `AbstractTableModel` so that it accepts a `TableModel` instead (this is an interface implemented by `AbstractTableModel`). This should be done anyway. Never depend on an concrete implementation when you can instead depend on an interface.

Then you can easily let class `AbstractModel` implement `TableModel`.

You should probably also think about creating an interface for `AbstractModel`. Usually one would create an interface `X`, an abstract base implementation `AbstractX` which provides common functionality shared by all implementations, and implementations `MyX`, `YourX` etc. Only the concrete implementations (but not necessarily all of them) would know and depend on `AbstractX`, but no code outside this hierarchy.

The Java Collections Framework is a good example of this: There is for example `List`, `AbstractList`, `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`, but there is no code that actually depends on an `AbstractList`. Most users of a list just use any `List`, or if they need a concrete implementation for some reason, they depend on that.

Comment: I do not think `List` and  `AbstractList` are a good comparison here. The latter has no public methods other than those inherited from the interface, while `AbstractTableModel` inherits less than half of its public methods from `TableModel`. Also, I see dozens of classes extending `AbstractTableModel`, but only two directly implementing `TableModel` (in a third-party library), so there is a lot of code actually depending on this one implementation rather than the interface.