# The elements not added to JList

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlist

I am trying to add file names to my JList but without success. Here is the piece of the code:

---

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
listLayer.setModel(model);
model.addElement(file.getName());
```

---

listLayer is a JList into which I would like to add file name. For information, I am writing my GUI application in netBeans so I can not create a new JList object within this code as it was already created automatically when added JList to my layout. Therefore I can just access it through its methods.

Thanks a lot,
Michal.

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------

### Ok I will try to extend it more:

```
private void openActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser("C:/");

    FileFilter filter1 = new MyCustomFilter();
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter1);

    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

            //String[] tokens = file.getName().split(".");
            //String name = tokens[0];

            DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
            listLayer.setModel(model);
            model.addElement(file.getName());

    } else {
        System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
        }
}
```

---

and yes, my JList called listLayer is declared in non-modifiable section of the code like this:
private javax.swing.JList listLayer;

Thanks again for any help. Michal

Comment: I've no idea why your code isn't working based on what you've posted.

Comment: Up-vote for adding important code -- thanks!

Comment: Don't let the [GUI designer](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+java+gui+designer) be an impediment.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting more code. Now quite possibly we can answer your question. A problem I see is that you're recreating a DefaultListModel each time the button is pressed and setting the JList with this new model effectively removing all data that was previously held by the list.  A way to avoid doing this is to simply get the model that the JList already has, which should be a DefaultListModel, and add items to it. You will need to cast the object returned by `getModel()` since per the API, Java only knows this to be a ListModel object, and ListModel doesn't have the `addElement(...)` method that DefaultListModel does.

Something perhaps like so:

```
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

        // note the cast since getModel() only returns a ListModel
        DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)listLayer.getModel(); // changed**

        model.addElement(file.getName());

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer, however it still doesnt work. I dont know what can be the problem. Maybe it will help if I tell that my JList is defined inside JPanel but dont know if this information is connected with the problem occured (I think no).

Comment: +1 good catch. I _think_ this is a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513).

Comment: @trashgod - in which point do you see a relation between my problem and problem you showed please? Thanks.

Comment: @MichalB: Your program models a selection of files using `DefaultListModel`, which is tied to a particular component and hides a somewhat dated implementation using `Vector`. A `List<File>` might be more flexible.

Comment: @trashgod - so if I understood it correctly you recommend me to use not DefaultListModel, but ListModel?

Answer (score 1):

> You recommend me to use not [`DefaultListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html), but `ListModel`?

I don't know enough about the rest of your program to say. If you have a single, relatively static `JList`, `DefaultListModel` may be perfect. If your program models a constantly changing selection of `File` instances, then you may want to implement `ListModel` or even a shared model, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572903/230513). The latter simply forwards some methods to the default implementation.